# If I use curl --interface eth1 will it specifically use eth1 no matter the metrics?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

Look at my routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    207    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     206    0        0 veth4557ad2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     207    0        0 eth1
```

I need to get the globa IP of my gateway `192.168.8.1`. For that I just need to `curl` [ifconfig.co](https://ifconfig.co/) in order to get the IP back. However, when I do

```
curl --interface eth1 ifconfig.co
```

it hangs forever. However for `wlan0` in place of `eth1` it works. Is it possible that the `metric 0` of `wlan0` is blocking something? Do you know a reason for the hanging?

Comment: Check the source ip.

Comment: @IporSircer it should be in the output of `netstat`? There is nothing connecting to the ifconfig.io's IP there

Comment: @A.B if it were using the default route, I should get the IP of the wlan0 gateway, but I don't get anything, it hangs. However when I use wlan0 I get the IP immediately. Also, what's the usefulness of `--interface` if the packets won't go out through the specified interface?